# DOJO: is it possible to display mouse co-ordinates on the graph using dojox.charting.Chart2D?

Tags: dojo

I want my graph some thing similar to Google finance graphs in the context of displaying x&y co-ordinates of the mouse when hover on the graph. Am using, DOJO's dojox.charting.Chart2D to draw the graph. Might be there is way to display the co-ordinates but i didn't find the option to display them. Please suggest me if some one is already used this or known before.
-Anju

Answer (score 0):

Just use a regular HTML and `onmousemove` event for that — the same way you can show mouse coordinates over an `image` element.